# Why `max()` won't use `nonlocal` var changed by a function in parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Or more specifically why `res` below is 1 for `max_f`?

```
def max_f():
    res = 0
    def f():
        nonlocal res
        res = max(res, 10)
        return 1
    res = max(res, f())  # res captured?
    return res
print(max_f())  # prints 1  

def if_f():
    res = 0
    def f():
        nonlocal res
        res = max(res, 10)
        return 1

    x = f()
    if x > res:
        res = x
    return res
print(if_f())  # prints 10
```

Comment: I'm not sure i can help you, but this sounds awfully confusing? is there really a proper use case for this?

Comment: in max_f, maybe its takes the value of res (`0`) before `f()` is executed (and changes res) ?

Comment: If you change `res = max(res, f())` into `k = f(); res =max(res, k)` then you get 10

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the order of evaluation in Python. When the line

```
res = max(res, f())
```

is met, first `res` is evaluated - which in that point is still `0` - and then `f()` is called. Then `max` is actually called as: `max(0, 1)`

If you change it to:

```
res = max(f(), res)
```

You will get the expected output

Comment: Reasonable but I thought Python can be more intelligible to first evaluate functions.

Comment: Why is that behavior bad? I believe it makes complete sense. Why will it jump ahead and calculate the function first? It can't assume you want that to happen. In Python you have to be explicit. Part of the Zen :)

Answer (score 1):

This code looks designed to confuse.

Regardless, you should add some print statements and see what's actually going on.

```
def max_f():
    res = 0
    print("step1res:",res)
    def f():
        nonlocal res
        res = max(res, 10)
        print("step_inside_res_f:",res)
        return 1
    print("NOTE HERE: res here is:", res )
    res = max(res, f())  # res captured?
    print("step3res:",res)
    return res
print(max_f())  # prints 1
```

Output:

```
step1res: 0
NOTE HERE: res here is: 0
step_inside_res_f: 10
step3res: 1
1
```

Essentially, Your function `f()` was only defined when you call the line  `res = max(res, f())` . In that line, the value for first argument is `0` as shown by `NOTE HERE: res here is: 0`.

Now, f() sets the `res` variable to 10, but returns 1. So `res = max(res, f())` then reassigns to `max(0, 1)`.

Thus, while `res` was momentarily set to 10, it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

```
in res = max(res, f())
```

when the code gets to this line it already has 0 in res now once you call f() res is changed but the return value of f() is 1 so what this code dose is.

```
res = max(0, 1)
```

thats why u get 1 as answer

Comment: Yeah, I see, but why Python does exactly this? Why not evaluate functions first?

Comment: In Tomerikoo 's Answer he has shown that only..Python follows top-down  and left to right ... like english